# save selection in a cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I trying to save the user seleccion in a cookie but I think I'm doing something wrong.

This is link in my view

```
<%= link_to image_tag("venezuela.png", :height => '74', :width => '111'),  {:controller => "landing", :action => "select_country", :country => "venezuela"}, :method => "get" %>
```

Here is the action of my controller

```
def select_country
        cookies.permanent[:country] = params[:country]
        case params[:country]
          when "venezuela"
            redirect_to "google.co.ve"
        end
  end
```

When I make click in the link a get this error:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for LandingController
```

and goes to this url

```
http://localhost:3000/landing/select_country?country=venezuela
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a routing problem. Make sure you don't have a route that assumes all links going to `/landing/:anything` are for the `show` action ahead of the route that defines `select_country` as an action on that controller.